# Update external variable by parameter function in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, updates

I have a page that generates values ​​according to the chosen parameter, this function should update an external variable which is also passed by parameter. But it does not work.

The variable enters with the same id, but at the time that the values ​​are generated and passed to this variable, it does not change externally.

This is the cógidos:

generator.py

```
import time 

def gera(value_start, value_end, value_step):
    while value_start <= value_end:
        yield value_start
        value_start += value_step

def update(current, new, var):
    print "var:", var, "  id(var):", id(var)        
    if (new >= current):
        current = new
        var = current
    print "var:", var, "  id(var):", id(var)        


def run(value_start, value_end, value_step, var):
    current = 0
    print "id(var):", id(var)  
    for x in gera(value_start, value_end, value_step):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        update(current, x, var)        
        print "\n", x
    print "id(var):", id(var)  
    print "var:", var
```

main.py

```
import generator
x= 30
print "x=",x, "  id(x)=", id(x)
print "\nX should come out with value 5 \n"
generator.run(1,5,1,x)
print x
```

However, the x does not have its value changed.
This is the output:

```
x= 30   id(x)= 37466652

X should come out with value 5 

id(var): 37466652
var: 30   id(var): 37466652
var: 1   id(var): 37467000

1
var: 30   id(var): 37466652
var: 2   id(var): 37466988

2
var: 30   id(var): 37466652
var: 3   id(var): 37466976

3
var: 30   id(var): 37466652
var: 4   id(var): 37466964

4
var: 30   id(var): 37466652
var: 5   id(var): 37466952

5
id(var): 37466652
var: 30
30
```

It appears that the ID stays the same, but outside of the function, because when it comes out, has a different id.
And the value that should end with 5, finishes with 30.

As I do for this program, have the variable of parameter X, with its value changes within the function.

Thank U.

Comment: Integers are immutable in Python...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what all those ids are supposed to be showing you, but the problem is that your update function does nothing. All that swapping the values inside that function does is assign them to new local names inside that function; it does not in any way affect the values assigned to names anywhere else.

Comment: Actually this is my problem. externally nothing changes.
What it should do is update the value of an existing label within a widget.
As the generator creates values, the label of this widget should show these values, but they do not.
What would be the right approach?